# Changing height of QInput focus border

Tags: css, quasar-framework

I'm trying to adjust the height of a qinput search field to match the buttons in my toolbar. I can't figure out how to change the height of the focus. I've created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/mlilback/pen/XWBrPjm) showing the problem trying various approaches.

[image: focus size problem]

I've been trying to change the color, then figure out how to adjust the height and border radius. Any ideas on what I need to do?

Here's the html:

```html
<q-input type="search" ref="searchField" v-model="searchFieldValue" size="xs" 
  style="max-width: 140px" @keyup.enter="doSearch" rounded outlined 
  input-class="mod-outline" input-style="font-size:14px" dense placeholder="Search"
  clearable clear-icon="close" class="search-field"
>
  <template v-slot:prepend>
    <q-icon name="search" size="xs"/>
  </template>
</q-input>
```

and the scss:

```css
.mod-outline:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border-color: green;
  border-radius: 0;
  max-height: 24px;
}
.search-field {
  max-height: 24px;
  .q-field__native:focus* {
    outline: none !important;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
  }
  .q-field__control {
    max-height: 24px;
    .q-field__prepend {
      max-height: 24px;
    }
    .q-field__control-container {
      max-height: 24px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So outline is made with pseudo element `::after` so when you add your desired css rules to `.q-field__control::after` you will get where you want to be.

```
.q-field__control {
     max-height: 24px;
     &::after {
      max-height: 24px;
      color: orange;
    }
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/sinisam92/pen/LYBPXJG)